# When installing azeothcore using ./acore docker build the build fails to what seems like networrk issues from within the container

Tags: azerothcore

The following error appears in the output:

```
#47 0.596 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports         /InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

#47 0.645 E: Unable to locate package dos2unix
#47 0.645 E: Unable to locate package gdb
#47 0.645 E: Unable to locate package gdbserver
#47 0.645 E: Unable to locate package google-perftools
#47 0.645 E: Unable to locate package libgoogle-perftools-dev
#47 0.645 E: Unable to locate package net-tools
#47 0.645 E: Unable to locate package libboost-system1.7*-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your `docker` and `docker-compose` version to `2.x`